# Changing multiple dropdowns option with one dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am learning angularjs and stuck at a situation where i want to bind the selected dropdown option to model/controller object. what i am trying to do is, All three dropdowns should show same option which is choosen in App1, later each dropdown can be changed depending on the usecase, want to save the clicks for user.

All three dropdown shows same option by assigning same ng-model as given for App1 dropdown, which works fine but the problem is what if the user changes any/all of the three dropdowns, i want to capture the one with option y and p choosen in an obect/array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Plunker here > https://plnkr.co/edit/HW1T3MxraceZawq3PmFT?p=preview

Comment: check this plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/KMksUASMbIM2UilfGJDg?p=preview)

Comment: I would suggest that you bind the three secondary drop downs to the variable in the controller you desire. When the user changes the app1 dropdown, it should kick off a function that resets those values in the controller. This way, the user can alter any values they want and everything is captured. If that makes sense, I can write up a quick demo, but I don't use plunker much.